# Copy lines based on a word using bat script from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a huge text file from which I just need copy only certain lines. I have written a bat script for the same. I navigate through the text file and consider only those lines which are prefixed by the word `"ResponseCode"`. The bat file is as below:

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist E:\output.txt del E:\output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (E:\test.txt) do (
    set "line0=%%i"
    set "line=!line0:*ResponseCode=!"
    if not "!line0!"=="!line!" (
        for /f %%j in ("!line!") do set "line=%%j"
        if not defined $a!line! (
            set "$a!line!=!line!"
            (echo(!line0!) >> E:\output.txt
        )
    )
)
```

But when I run the above script it copies just one line from `test.txt` instead of four as expected and write it to `output.txt`. How can I make it copy all the four lines that contain `ResponseCode` as the prefix word?

Comment: Is `ResponseCode` the first thing in the lines of interest? could there be any leading white-spaces? do you want `ResponseCode` _not_ to be written to `output.txt`? does the case of letters matter?

Comment: The lines start like this to be specific `"&amp;lt;ResponseCode"`. But the other things apart from `ResponseCode` could vary. That's why I took it as a reference. I need the data that follows the `ResponseCode`, so it doesn't matter if `ResponseCode` is written or not. Yes the case does matter, because it's obtained that way in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findstr /L "ResponseCode" "E:\test.txt"` will return all lines that contain `ResponseCode` literally.
The returned lines can be easily redirected to your output file by appending `>> "E:\output.txt"`.

The following code parses the output of `findstr` and outputs everything *after* `ResponseCode`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem.> "E:\output.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L "ResponseCode" "E:\test.txt"') do (
  set "LINE=%%L" & set "LINE=!LINE:*ResponseCode=!" & echo !LINE!
) >> "E:\output.txt"
endlocal
```

Note that `findstr` performs a case-sensitive search as `/I` is *not* given; however, removal of everything to the (first) occurrence of `ResponseCode` (by expansion `!LINE:*ResponseCode=!`) is accomplished in a case-**in**sensitive manner!

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this instead?

```
findstr /b ResponseCode "E:\test.txt" >>"E:\output.txt"
```

The /b tells it to only output the line if "ResponseCode" exists at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I had tried that, before taking the above questioned approach. Returns a blank `output.txt` with absolutely no data

Comment: Can you try running the command against files on your C drive? Just to see if it's a permissions issue, the FINDSTR line did work when I tested it on my machine.

Comment: If "_by running the command against files on my C drive_" u mean to run the script for files present on my C folder, I did that too but still the result remains unchanged.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I meant... Can you try outputting the output.txt file to your "My documents" folder? I have seen issues before with scripts writing to root directories

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here? Is it working?

Comment: No it's not. It's writing the script itself on the output file infinitely

Comment: Can you try just issuing this on a command line and see what the output gives you?         findstr /b ResponseCode "E:\test.txt"